# Can't use foreign key in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get a table to have a foreign key linking to another table in my hierarchy however I cannot get it to work at all if anyone can advise that'd be great, i'm getting the error ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list.

```
CREATE TABLE name 
(column_1_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
    column_2 VARCHAR2(200), 
    column3 VARCHAR2(200), 
    PRIMARY KEY (column_1_ID));

CREATE TABLE name2
(bcolumn_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
    bcolumn_1_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL REFERENCES name(column_1_ID), 
    Name VARCHAR2(500), PRIMARY KEY(bcolumn_ID, bcolumn_1_ID));

CREATE TABLE name_3 
(ccolumn_1_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
    ccolumn_2_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL REFERENCES name(column_1_ID), 
    ccolumn_3 VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(ccolumn_1_ID, ccolumn_2_ID));

CREATE TABLE name4 
(dcolumn_1_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
    dcolumn_2 VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    dcolumn_3_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL REFERENCES name_3(ccolumn_1_ID),
    dcolumn4 VARCHAR2(100), 
    dcolumn_5 NUMBER(5,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY(dcolumn_1_ID,dcolumn_3_ID));

CREATE TABLE name5 
(ecolumn_1_ID NOT NULL REFERENCES name4(dcolumn_1_ID), 
    ecolumn_2_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
    ecolumn_3 NUMBER(5,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY(ecolumn_1_ID, ecolumn_2_ID));
```

I'm wanting name3(ccolumn_1_ID) to be a foreign key to name4. I'm also wanting name4(dcolumn_2) to have a constraint which only allows "value" "value2" and "value3" but I get a missing right parenthesis error. Any help is appreciated!
​

Answer (score 1):

Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm) is rather clear:

> Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an **alphabetic** character from
>   your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any
>   character.

Give your columns names that don't start with a number.  So, `2column_ID` is not valid, unless surrounded by double quotes.  But don't do that.  Come up with a better name.

Comment: apologies used that name as an example, the names do in fact start with alphabetical characters

Answer (score 0):

name_3 table has a composited primary key, so if you want a foreign key you need to use two columns, let dcolumn_3_ID be the first:

```
CREATE TABLE name4 
(dcolumn_1_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
    dcolumn_2 VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    dcolumn_3_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
    dcolumn4 VARCHAR2(100), 
    dcolumn_5 NUMBER(5,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY(dcolumn_1_ID,dcolumn_3_ID),
    constraint fk_name_3 FOREIGN KEY(dcolumn_3_ID, <Put the column that matches name_3.ccolumn_2_ID>) 
    references name_3(ccolumn_1_ID, ccolumn_2_ID));
```

anyhow you'll need a second column that matches `ccolumn_2_ID` type VARCHAR2(60).

You'll have the same error in table `name5`. (by the way please add your second attempt to solve the problem instead of changing the original question, so others can help you too)

Comment: apologies used that name as an example, the names do in fact start with alphabetical characters

Comment: CREATE TABLE name4 
    (dcolumn_1_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL, 
    dcolumn_2 VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    dcolumn_3_ID VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
    dcolumnnew <matching name_3.ccolumn>
    dcolumn4 VARCHAR2(100), 
    dcolumn_5 NUMBER(5,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY(dcolumn_1_ID,dcolumn_3_ID),
    constraint fk_name_3 FOREIGN KEY(dcolumn_3_ID, dcolumnnew),
    references name_3(ccolumn_1_ID, ccolumn_2_ID));
Now im getting missing right parenthesis, please tell me im an idiot and cant see what im doing

Comment: sorted it but now im missing a keyword, code same as above but with comma after dcolumnnew

Comment: Please add another question, as it seems another problem with another answer.